# Custom annotation to suppress a specific FindBugs warning

Tags: java, annotations, findbugs

I want to create custom annotations to suppress individual FindBugs warnings to make it easier to use them via code-completion. For example, this one ignores constructors that don't set all `@Nonnull` fields.

```
@TypeQualifierDefault(ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR)
@SuppressFBWarnings("NP_NONNULL_FIELD_NOT_INITIALIZED_IN_CONSTRUCTOR")
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
public @interface SuppressNonnullFieldNotInitializedWarning
{ }
```

However, I still see the warning when using the annotation.

```
public class User {
    @Nonnull
    private String name;

    @SuppressNonnullFieldNotInitializedWarning
    public User() {
        // "Nonnull field name is not initialized by new User()"
    }
}
```

I've tried different retention policies and element types, putting the annotation on the constructor and the class, and even `@TypeQualifierNickname`.

This same pattern works to apply `@Nonnull` to all fields in a class.

```
@Nonnull
@TypeQualifierDefault(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface FieldsAreNonnullByDefault
{ }
```

FindBugs correctly displays a warning for code that assigns `null` to `name`.

```
@FieldsAreNonnullByDefault
public class User {
    private String name;

    public UserModel() {
        name = null;
        // "Store of null value into field User.name annotated Nonnull"
    }
}
```

I believe the problem is that `@SuppressFBWarnings` is not marked with `@TypeQualifier` while `@Nonnull` is, and thus `@TypeQualifierDefault` and `@TypeQualifierNickname` don't apply to it. But there must be some other mechanism to apply one annotation using another.

Comment: @Chris: That answer describes how to use the findbugs SuppressWarning annotation.  This question is how to create a new annotation that suppresses a specific findbugs warning.

Comment: @Chris You posted the second link already here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14285422/custom-annotation-to-suppress-a-specific-findbugs-warning#comment19837178_14285422

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Not specifically answering the question), but if you just want to make code-completion work better with `@SuppressFBWarnings`, you could define a `static final String` for each of the warning codes and then use those in the annotation.  e.g.

```
public final class FBWarningCodes {
    private FBWarningCodes() { }

    public static final String NP_NONNULL_FIELD_NOT_INITIALIZED_IN_CONSTRUCTOR = "NP_NONNULL_FIELD_NOT_INITIALIZED_IN_CONSTRUCTOR";
}
```

Then:

```
import static com.tmobile.tmo.cms.service.content.FBWarningCodes.*;

@SuppressFBWarnings(NP_NONNULL_FIELD_NOT_INITIALIZED_IN_CONSTRUCTOR)
```

(though admittedly Eclipse doesn't want to do code-completion unless you specify `value=` in the annotation)

Comment: This is my current solution, though I shorten the constant names.

Comment: Here's a template for Eclipse users: fb - `@${suppress:newType(edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressFBWarnings)}(${warning:newType(com.tmobile.tmo.cms.service.content.FBWarningCodes)}.${cursor})` Type `fb`, hit Ctrl-Space twice, and select the warning to suppress.